# Add targets to CloudWatch Event Rules using CDK in golang

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am fairly new to typescript CDK for aws and am trying to deploy a lambda function using CDK in typescript with something like this:

```
const lambdaFn = new lambda.Function(..);
```

Now, I am trying to create an event rule  which needs to trigger this lambda function. When I add the `targets` part (shown below) in the rule, I see an error shown below.

```
const rule = new events.Rule(
  this,
  'Rule',
  {
    eventPattern: {"source": [ "aws.organizations" ], "detail": { "eventName": [ "CreateAccountResult" ] } },
    targets: [ new targets.LambdaFunction(lambdaFn) ] // <<<--- this line throws exceptions..
  }
);
```

Exception I see:

```
lib/test.ts:26:20 - error TS2322: Type 'LambdaFunction' is not assignable to type 'IRuleTarget'.
  Types of property 'bind' are incompatible.
    Type '(rule: IRule, _id?: string | undefined) => RuleTargetConfig' is not assignable to type '(rule: IRule, id?: string | undefined) => RuleTargetConfig'.
      Types of parameters 'rule' and 'rule' are incompatible.
26         targets: [ new targets.LambdaFunction(lambdaFn) ]
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..
..
..
lib/test.ts:26:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFunction'.
  Types of property 'role' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/shubham/workspace/ft/organization-management-services/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role").IRole | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/shubham/workspace/ft/organization
..
..
26         targets: [ new targets.LambdaFunction(lambdaFn) ]
                                                 ~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue that's documented here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/issues/89